# Java Queue Peek() keeps return newest entry and not first entered

Tags: java, queue

I am trying to peek at my queue and grab the first entry so then i can press the remove button to get rid of it however the peek is showing the last entered instead of the first. I have tried both peek and peek front.

```
private int maxSize;
private String[] queArray;
private int front;
private int rear;
private int nItems;
public String FN,LN,PN,Email,Addres,State,Zip,LicensePlate;

public Queue(String fN, String lN, String pN, String email, String address, String state, String zip,
        String licensePlate) {

    maxSize++;

    queArray = new String[maxSize];
    front = 0;
    rear = -1;
    nItems = 0;
    FN = fN;
    LN = lN;
    PN = pN;
    Email = email;
    Addres = address;
    State = state;
    Zip = zip;
    LicensePlate = licensePlate;

}

public void insert(String FN, String LN, String PN, String Email, String Addres, String State, String Zip,
        String LicensePlate) {
    String input = "{" + "First Name: "+ FN + ", " +"  Last Name: "+ LN +", "+"   Phone Number: "+ PN + ", " +"  Email: "+ Email +", " +"  Address: "+ Addres + ", " +"  State: "+  State +", "+"  Zip: "+  Zip + ", " +"  LicensePlate: "+ LicensePlate + "}";
    if (rear == maxSize - 1)
        rear = -1;
    queArray[++rear] = input;
    nItems++;
    }

  public String peekFront() {

    return queArray[front++];
}

public String peek() {
    return queArray[front];
}
```

Fixed by changing maxSize++ to maxSize = 5

Comment: Is this code inside a Queue class ? can you provide a simple code sample of how you use that and what's wrong ?

Comment: This is because you are using front for inserting the new element. Every time you add one element, executing an increment operation on front variable so it will always point to the last element added to the queue. If you want the first one, you need a second variable "head", that stays on the front element of the queue. So use two variables, _one for handling the tail_ of this data structure and _one for the head_. The former when inserting an element at the end of queue, with the second for retrieving operations.

Comment: i am supposed to make the class itself not use the import wish i could its easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaking, this is happening, because of your maxSize mechanism.

maxSize is never set to a Number only once incremented with `maxSize++`. So maxSize is always 1.

Now when one Element is already inserted, the following Code gets called, because rear is now 0 and maxSize-1=1-1.

`if (rear == maxSize - 1)
        rear = -1;
    queArray[++rear] = input;`

You are simply overwriting the only Element in the Array.

Instead of writing your own array based queue which holds your data, consider using a custom object for your data and a already implemented queue like [java.util.Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: I think you were correct i changed maxsize++ to a number and now everything is working fine thank you